# Feed the MATLAB structure output to a new structure

Tags: matlab, structure, matlab-struct

If I have a MATLAB structure output like

```
f1: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
f2: 'a'
```

How can I feed this output to different structure without manually doing

```
F = struct('f1', [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0], 'f2', 'a');
```

In other words I need to feed the data in format

```
'field' : value
```

printed elsewhere in my live script notebook  to a new structure. So far I am thinking about creating a binary file, but I thought there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Just reassign it to a new variable. This works since MATLAB utilize [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). Any changes to the new copy will not be reflected in the original.

```
F = struct('f1', [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0], 'f2', 'a');
F2 = F;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you understood my problem. I need to feed the data in format 'field' : value to a new structure. So far I am thinking about creating a binary file, but I thought there must be a better way.

Comment: @belarus This *does* create a new structure...Maybe show an explicit example of what you want?

Comment: Ok, see the first section of the code in the question. How can you assign these fields and values separated by colon to a new structure?

Comment: Oh so you didn't just print those from an existing structure?

Comment: @belarus You're trying to go from a *string* to a struct? Were those values ever in a struct?

Comment: Yes it was printed from a structure previously but I use that variable continuously so I do want to convert string to a structure.

Comment: @belarus Why not just use the struct rather than the printed string?

Comment: I keep my lab notebook in matlab live script. I print fitting parameters as an output and keep it for my reference. Occasionally I need to go back and feed it to different fitting function.